# Logical and (&&) type of operator only for null types in Javascript

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting, logical-and, nullish-coalescing

The logical && operator returns the left side iff it is evaluated as 'falsy'.

```
null && 10 
> null
0 && 10  
> 0
1 && 10 
> 10
```

The nullish coalescing operator (??) returns the left side iff it is not null or undefined.

```
null ?? 10
> 10
0 ?? 10
> 0
1 ?? 10
> 1
```

Is there any neat expression to return the left side iff it is null or undefined?
Basically, this would be && only for null or undefined and would look like this:

```
null xx 10
> null
0 xx 10
> 10
1 xx 10
> 10
```

I need to do the following quite often when parsing default values and it becomes a little tedious to read when `someVar` gets chained and `parse` contains more than one function.

```js
defaults?.someVar != null ? parse(defaults.someVar) : null
```